# How to get green channel using ImageJ?

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I am processing an image using ImageJ as a library and I need to get the green channel of an RGB image. Does ImageJ have a method for that purpose? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the GUI it's

Image -> Color -> Split Channels.

Progammatically ColorProcesor contains a method

```
getChannel(int i) .
```

There is also a Plugin called ChannelSplitter.